# PSQL select all rows with a non-unique column

Tags: sql, postgresql

The query is supposed to query the `item` table and:

- filter out `active=0` items
- select `id` and `groupId` where there's at least one more item with that `groupId`

### Example:

```
| id  | groupId | active |
| --- | ------- | ------ |
| 1   | 1       | 1      |
| 2   | 2       | 1      |
| 3   | 2       | 0      |
| 4   | 3       | 1      |
| 5   | 3       | 1      |
| 6   | 4       | 1      |
```

**Desired Output:**

```
| id  | groupId |
| --- | ------- |
| 4   | 3       |
| 5   | 3       |
```

**Explanation**

- `groupID` 1: **invalid** because has only 1 member
- `groupID` 2: **invalid** because has two members, but one is inactive
- `groupID` 3: **valid**
- `groupID` 4: **invalid** because has only 1 member

**What I tried**

```sql
SELECT id, groupId
FROM items
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id 
    FROM items
    WHERE active=1
    GROUP BY groupId
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  );
```

But I get the `id must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` error.
I understand I can mess around with the `sql_mode` to get rid of that error, but I would rather avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for window functions:

```
select i.*
from (select i.*, count(*) over (partition by groupid) as cnt
      from items i
      where active = 1
     ) i
where cnt > 1
```

Comment: Do you know whether your solution is more/less efficient than @isaace's

Comment: @VolodymyrBobyr . . . I would expect window functions to be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Window functions is the way to go.

But if you want to fix your query then this should do it:

```
select a.id, a.groupId from items a
where active = 1 and groupid in(
    select groupId from item 
    where active = 1
    group by groupId
    having count(distinct id) > 1
)
```

because we are counting which groupid has more than 1 id for the same groupid

Comment: Ah I like this solution, thank you. There's a small logic error in it though, the `active=1` check should be in both the outer and the inner query, because your solution will return valid groups, but those groups will also have inactive items. I probably should have included this case in my original example

Comment: so if a groupId has 2 active id's and 1 not active then this groupId should be filtered out?

Comment: nope, the inactive rows should just not appear in the final results. so the groupId would have 2/3 items